# Is it possible to use environment variables in Orbeon service URLs?

Tags: orbeon

For example, in our Orbeon test environment we'd like the service URL to be: `https://test.some-endpoint.com/validate`.

Then when the form is deployed in the production environment, the service URL should automatically change to: `https://prod.some-endpoint.com/validate`.

I recognize that I could create a hidden field to store the environment value, but this wouldn't automatically change when the form is deployed in the production environment. See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Orbeon Forms 2020.1, you can use the [`environment-variable('SERVICE_HOST')` function](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/standard-functions#environment-variable). So, assuming you have a environment variable named `SERVICE_HOST`, in the HTTP Service Editor you can use the following for the Resource URL:

```
https://{environment-variable('SERVICE_HOST')}.some-endpoint/validate
```

Comment: As a footnote, as I am writing this, Orbeon Forms 2020.1 hasn't been released yet, but is expected to be released before the end of the year. Also, just let me know if you'd like to give a shot to a pre-release.

Comment: Thanks @avernet I'm pleased to hear that this feature is in the works.